# How to include the current commit in a snakemake workflow for later reference?

Tags: git, snakemake

My snakemake workflow lives under version control in a git repository. I'm after a possibility to include something like the output of `git describe --always` to track the git tag/commit the workflow repository is currently checked out to **during** runtime of the workflow.

I added a generic function in the workflow, that just calls git via `subprocess`:

```
def get_git_commit(wildcards):
  label = subprocess.check_output(["git", "describe", "--always"]).strip().decode("utf-8")
  return(label)
```

The output can be used in rule *params*, e.g.

```
  params:
    git_commit = get_git_commit
```

However, during runtime of the workflow, the command is executed in the working directory, not the source directory of the Snakefile. Is `cd`ing back and forth (into the source directory) advisable? Or are there cleaner strategies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Snakefile is in the same folder as the .git folder, you can get the path of the Snakefile (directly in the Snakefile) with:

```
wfbasedir = workflow.basedir
```

You can then invoke git with the parameter `--git-dir`:

```
git --git-dir={wfbasedir}/.git
```

or your way with:

```
def get_git_commit(wildcards):
    label = subprocess.check_output(["git","--git-dir="+wfbasedir+"/.git", "describe", "--always"]).strip().decode("utf-8")
    return(label)
```